# Is it possible to apply for a work visa (blue card?) for Germany while you have a French D-Category (family reunion) visa?

Tags: working-visas, germany, france, schengen, blue-card

I have an interesting situation here.

I am a non-Schengen country citizen while my wife is a French national.
We decided to move to France and obtained a family reunion visa with a year duration starting from December. Meanwhile, I got a job offer from a company in Germany and I am considering take the job.

However I already have a visa although different category and from a different country. What is the best course of action here. Do I need to contact to French Consulate and ask for cancellation of my visa and start proceedings with German consulate or else there is a simpler way of getting a work visa from Germany?

Comment: Would your wife move to Germany?

Comment: @Relaxed yes, she will be with me.